# Clojure : Are symbols standard data type to pass between functions from different clj fies?

Tags: exception, clojure, symbols

I have a program that im wrapping, in clojure.

The program has some symbols it uses to start up, as input.

I've created a simple UI to convert user entered strings to symbols using a map.

```
#expect user to enter "boat" 
(def input (read-line))

(def ops '{"boat" b})

(if 
  # check if the value of the key is a valid symbol
  (in? '(a b c) (ops input))

  #if so , run class
  (start (ops input))

  #end
  (print "didnt find " input " in options , fail.\n")
)
```

The logic works, however, the program crashes once it reaches the "start" call...  This makes me think that, for some reason, the symbol "b" in '(a b c) doesn't match up with b as declared in the program which is being called (i.e. the one which i havent shown here).

It is quite obvious that this problem is uninteresting, so my real question is : should I be parsing strings into symbols which i send as control structures to another program ? Or is there a better way to invoke an external clj script which uses raw Symbols as internal inputs.  I would appreciate any specifics regarding why the program is crashing ... but since I havent provided much code, i dont expect anyone to be able to magically "know" what is wrong here in any detailed sense.

Comment: Instead of `'{"boat" b}`, you should have `{"boat" 'b}` -- you don't want to quote the whole map, just the symbol `b`.

Comment: @MattFenwick Those evaluate to the same thing (although `{"boat" 'b}` may or may not be more idiomatic).

Answer (score 4):

How is your program crashing?

<strike>Symbols belong in namespaces, and if you don't take that into account, you can end up comparing different symbols with the same name. In your case you may prefer to use keywords instead (starting with colon like ":keyword").</strike>

The program, that you show here isn't valid clojure. You're using sharp (#) as start of comment character, but it's not.  You should use semicolon for that.

Some other minor points:

- You don't need to quote the map, it's not evaluated
- You can use sets instead of (in? '(a b c) (ops input)) like this: (#{a b c} (ops input)). It's faster and more idiomatic

**Update:** Generally, symbols in clojure do *not* belong to namespaces (see comments).

Comment: If `{"boat" b}` weren't quoted, `b` would be evaluated.

Comment: Also, symbols do not belong to namespaces unless they are put there (e.g. by being quasi-quoted).

Comment: @MatthiasBenkard I assumed this is only part of the file (not the whole thing), and I also assumed that the OP have put namespace declarations at the top. Maybe I assumed too much? In any case, comparing symbols from different namespaces seems the most likely problem (besides the # symbol)

Comment: A namespace declaration doesn't change the fact that literal symbols are not namespaced by default.  Try it out: Put `(ns eu.mulk.foo) (def x 'hello) (println (namespace x))` into a file and load that file.  The result will be a printout of `nil`.  Clojure handles interning differently from Common Lisp and related dialects.

Comment: @MatthiasBenkard Thanks for that! I was really imagining Common Lisp-like namespaces.

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to have strings in that list

```
'("a" "b" "c")
```

unless a,b,c symbols are bound to strings elsewhere ?

Comment: Why? (ops "boat") evaluates to the symbol b, not to the string "b".

Comment: because the map links the sting to the symbol - {"boat" b}

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. AFAICT, the OP wants to map input strings to symbols for easier comparison, and his map does that.

Comment: yes but the read-line returns a string ? I think he means to use keywords not symbols as well ?